# how to catch the click event for Customheaderbutton in groupcontrol ( DevExpress )

Tags: c#, button, devexpress

I 'm having problems in getting the click event in groupcontrol customheaderbutton , hope everyone guide !

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36892374/edit) your question and add some of your code. Otherwise we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CustomButtonClick` event of `GroupControl` like this :

```
private void groupControl1_CustomButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.BaseButtonEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Button caption: " + e.Button.Properties.Caption);
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer if is it correct for other people, Thank you.